# jQuery unbinding toggle on setinterval function

Tags: jquery, toggle

I am trying to unbind a function that toggles/switches between two html elements every 2 seconds, and when moused over the function should stop so people can see the element for as long as they wish.

I will later add bind the function back to resume the toggle on mouseout.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function switchBox() {
        $('#imagebox7img').toggle('slow', 'linear');
        $('#map-canvas').toggle('slow', 'linear');
    }
    // hide image
    $('#imagebox7img').hide();
    // set timer and function
    setInterval(switchBox, 2000);
    // disable function on hover
    $('#imagebox7img').mouseover(function () {
        $(this).unbind();
    });
}); // end ready
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**setInterval**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) returns unique interval ID you can pass to [**clearInterval**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval) to cancel repeated action.

```
    // set timer and function
    var interval = setInterval(switchBox, 2000);
    $('#imagebox7img').mouseover(function () {
        clearInterval(interval )
    });
```

Comment: ah! thanks very much, I was coming at it from the wrong angle! To then re-start the switchBox function I can simply setInterval(switchBox, 2000) on mouseout. thanks very much

Comment: I don't suppose you would know why this doesn't work with googlemaps?